# Creating multiple users in Firebase at the same time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Well, not exactly at the same time. More like one after the other, in a for-loop.

**Problem:** So in some instances, the code I used did manage to create multiple accounts but it often gives me the error that the user is null and fails to write to the database.

**The code:**

```
Database db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String password = "1234567"; // Same password for all accounts
ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList(); // For example, 20 premade emails

        for (int i = 0; i < emailArray.size(); i++){
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword((String) emailArray.get(i), password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                        
                     String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();  // This value is returning null
                     
                     // Writing a bunch of things to the database for each user 
                     db.child(userId).child("name").setValue(...)
                     ...

                     mAuth.signOut();
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I think I may have to use an AuthStateListener but I am unsure and I don't know how to implement it. How would I go about accomplishing this? Please let me know if I should include anything else in my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the client-side Android SDK to create multiple users like this. There's a significant chance that your app will be flagged for abuse, and locked out of the system.

For administrative use-cases, use the Admin SDK in a trusted environment.

---

On a code level, the problem occurs because there's only one value for `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` and you're trying to create all the users in parallel. You'll need to wait for each `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to be completed, before starting on the next one. But as said above: this approach is flawed to begin with, so I don't recommend pursuing this path further.

Comment: In my case, I am trying to create multiple accounts for testing purposes of various recycler views. Instead of manually having to create hundreds of accounts, I wanted to create them in bulk. Can this be done with Admin SDK?

Comment: Yes. The Admin SDK can [create users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with a much higher quota, or you can [import users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users) without ever hitting quota limits.